# What are extra feature cyanogen ROM provide in compare of Default Google provided ROM

Tags: android, rom

Can anybody let me know features of features cyanogen, who develop this.
Is it by hackers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the official website: http://www.cyanogenmod.com/about for a full list of features.
And the community members at http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Community_Members
The lead developer has just recently been employed by Samsung.

> "CyanogenMod is a customized, aftermarket firmware distribution for
>   several Android devices. Based on the Android Open Source
>   Project, CyanogenMod is designed to increase performance and
>   reliability over Android-based ROMs released by vendors and carriers. CyanogenMod also offers a variety features & enhancements that are not currently found in these versions of Android"

Answer (score 1):

I am a CyanogenMod user and the great thing about it is that it is constantly improving and evolving. If you look at their github repo https://github.com/cyanogenmod you'll see that they support tons of phones and have just as many features.

Lots of people contribute to it and thats what makes it great.

I suggest taking a look at their website and accompanying forums if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

The ROM is developed by different developers. Anyone who has has a knowledge of coding can develop a ROM, but in Cyanogen the developers have good knowledge in coding. So in Cyanogen they try to improve the performace, themes, battery perfomance, Ram management, updates and everything better than your Stock Rom. One more feature in Cyanogen is it it rooted inbuilt. So you don;t have to root your device. JUst flashing the ROM is necessary. CM Theme engine is the best feature.

Answer (score 0):

CM ROM build by an Organisation and open source can be found [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEnKTz-LbRAhVMvI8KHR7ICswQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdownload.cyanogenmod.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNGIMNFRS1Om3oPhEJNWh6JBaP7Dwg&sig2=QYGSSAy5SkHSL0852Atauw&bvm=bv.143423383,d.c2I). & could be more source to get it. They worked on vanilla build got form Google and worked better then what Google engineer did. Huge improvement  in performance and theme.

But with latest version of Android OS 7.0 [naugat](https://www.android.com/versions/nougat-7-0/) it gonna be different game now. Let's see what CM will bring up.